# Haskell: how is readMay evaluated?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I was looking at a [tutorial in School of Haskell](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/functors-applicative-functors-and-monads), when a particular piece of code puzzled me. The snippet below, in my opinion, should not work, but it does. There is something about the evaluation of `readMay` in this case that I didn't quite understand.

```
import Safe (readMay)

main = do
  putStrLn "Please enter your birth year"
  yearString <- getLine
  case readMay yearString of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid year"
    Just year -> putStrLn $ "In 2020, you'll be " ++ show (2020 - year)
```

Shouldn't `readMay yearString` (`:t readMay = Read a => String -> Maybe a`) always evaluate to `Nothing`, since I am not forcing its type? For this code to work, the resulting expression of the `case` statement would have to be computed first, since the expression `2020 - year` would require `year` to belong to the `Num` typeclass, thus allowing `readMay yearString` to evaluate to `Just year`.

Comment: Nice example. Type inference can be surprisingly smart, at the beginning.

Comment: Actually, the type to be used is ambiguous here. It only works due to GHC "magic" - it defaults the type to `readMay :: String -> Maybe Integer`. If you turn on warnings, you will see this.

Comment: @user2407038 I was wondering about that... I assumed it must be defaulting rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell decides what the types should be at *compile-time*. Either it figures out what the return type for `readMay` should be, or it refuses to compile the code due to a type error.

By the time the code runs, Haskell already "knows" what type `readMay` should be returning. If the string actually presented won't parse, you'll get `Nothing`.

In short, this has *nothing to do with* lazy evaluation. This is about compile-time verses run-time. [Which may not be that obvious if you're just running this from GHCi.]

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this is not very obvious when you just `runhaskell source.hs` everything.

Answer (score 3):

If the result type of `readMay` could not be determined, the code would fail to compile with an "ambiguous type" error. It would not evaluate to `Nothing`.

So why don't you get that error? Haskell can determine the type by looking at the types inside the case statement first. However that does not mean that the inside is evaluated first - it's not, it's only type inferred first. Type checking and inference happens at compile time and is completely separate from evaluation. The order of type inference does not affect the order of evaluation.